# How can I prevent water coming out of the shower head

Tags: plumbing, bathroom

I have a dual valve manifold and a plunger bath tub spigot. When I turn the water on and the plunger is down, the water pressure will build up and come out of the shower head. I took the spigot off and it stopped. But I’ve bought 3 different spigots and all of them cause the water pressure to build up and come out of the shower head. Any suggestions!?!!

Comment: You can get a small cut-off valve that fits between the shower head and the outlet pipe. https://www.build.com/delta-52652-pk-shower-head/s244417?uid=1907341&source=gg-gba-pla_1907341!c959312063!a50442201311!dc!ng&gclid=Cj0KCQjwx43ZBRCeARIsANzpzb9uh5ieztXxN2RLKnsGxEmNEz4mvBpLcNSsgoNMUMU27GM3bPmcBtAaAn6qEALw_wcB But why do you care if a little water comes out the shower head? It goes into the tub doesn't it?

Comment: @JimStewart, the link that you posted is a shower head with a builtin valve

Comment: Thanks, but there are connecting valves with F-threads on one end and M-threads on the other which can be used with an existing shower head.

Comment: This is very unusual because the water should take the path of least resistance, which is out of the tub spout. The restrictions through the tub/shower control valves should be smaller, collectively, than any restriction posed by the tub spout and associated piping that leads to it. When you say you "took the spigot off and it stopped", what exactly did you do, leave a bare iron or copper pipe sticking out into the tub, then flow water?